# How to make a tab selected everytime the user logs into the application?

Tags: iphone, authentication, uitabbarcontroller

In my application i am using a tabbar controller where it contains 4 tabs.In one of the tab, Log out functionality is added where i am presenting the login view controller on click of log out tab. now when the user logs in i want the 1st tab selected defaulty. How to set that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this way:

```
TabBarController* tabBar =  thisIsYourTabBarInstance; //
[tabBar setSelectedIndex:4];
```

to get TabBarController in your tab's child `UIViewController` use

```
TabBarController* tabBar = [self tabBarController];
```

make a method in app delegate like this

in AppDelegate.h file

```
- (void)userIsLoggedOut;
```

and AppDelegate.m file

```
- (void)userIsLoggedOut    
{
    TabBarController* tabBar =  thisIsYourTabBarInstance; //
    [tabBar setSelectedIndex:4];
}
```

now anywhere write this:

```
AppDelegate *d= (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[d userIsLoggedOut];
```

Comment: This is valid only in Appdelegate because i am loading my tabbar in appdelegate. but my tabbar is not called again as it will be called only once...

Comment: if you are in your sub controller of `TabBarController`, you can get instance by `[self tabBarController]`

Comment: After logging out i am preseting my login view controller as a modal view controller. So my login view controller is not a sub controller of TabBarController. From here i need to set the selected index of the  TabBar controller(in AppDelegate) to 0 everytime. Can u please help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Set a NSUSerDefault on the log out that determines which view to show first in the tabbarController in the AppDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

You can set active tab in viewDidLoad method of your tabBarController

[[self tabBarController] setSelectedIndex:0];